# Soap Header Exception Unexpected element

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, xsd, wsdl

One of the webservices that we use in our ASP.Net product have issued a new WSDL. But they claim that there is no functionality change.
Since I am getting an exception, I am trying to compare the old and new WSDLs.
I see some format "language" differences.
Are these two different ways of expressing the Soap WSDL,
or are these following two different versions of schema writing? I could not find any mention of this online.

I am still a newbie to .Net world!
Should I just go ahead and recreate the references in .Net product simply and be done with it?

Anyways, this is the exception

```
Error Type: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException
Error Message: Unexpected element {urn:SOAP_PmtPortal_Server}newOrder found.   Expected {urn:ServerPmtPortal}newOrderRequest.
Error Source: System.Web.Services
Stack Trace:    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
```

I am including the old and the new WSDL (stripping off all but one operation)

OLD WSDL (For the new WSDL, please see after this section)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<definitions name="ServerPmtPortal" targetNamespace="urn:ServerPmtPortal" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
xmlns:tns="urn:ServerPmtPortal" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
<types xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"> </types>

<message name="newOrderRequest">
  <part name="appID" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="merID" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="redURL" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="uname" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="cmt" type="xsd:string" />
</message>

<message name="newOrderResponse">
  <part name="tranID" type="xsd:string" />
</message>

<portType name="ServerPmtPortalPort">
  <operation name="newOrder">
    <input message="tns:newOrderRequest" />
    <output message="tns:newOrderResponse" />
  </operation>
</portType>

<binding name="ServerPmtPortalBinding" type="tns:ServerPmtPortalPort">
  <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
  <operation name="newOrder">
   <soap:operation 
      soapAction="urn:SOAP_PmtPortal_Server#SOAP_PmtPortal_Server#newOrder" />
     <input>
     <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:SOAP_PmtPortal_Server" 
       encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
    </input>
    <output>
      <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:SOAP_PmtPortal_Server" 
      encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
    </output>
   </operation>

</binding>
<service name="ServerPmtPortalService">
  <documentation />
  <port name="ServerPmtPortalPort" binding="tns:ServerPmtPortalBinding">
    <soap:address location="https://www.service.com/paynow/service/server.php" />
  </port>
</service>

</definitions>
```

NEW WSDL is like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
xmlns:tns="urn:ServerPmtPortal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" name="ServerPmtPortalService" 
targetNamespace="urn:ServerPmtPortal">

<wsdl:types>
  <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:ServerPmtPortal" version="1.0">

    <xs:element name="newOrderRequest">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
          <xs:element name="appID" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="merID" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="redURL" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="uname" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="cmt" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:all>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="newOrderResponse">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="tranID" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

  </xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
  
<wsdl:message name="newOrder">
  <wsdl:part element="tns:newOrderRequest" name="body">
  </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="newOrderResponse">
  <wsdl:part element="tns:newOrderResponse" name="body">
  </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:portType name="ServerPmtPortalPort">
   <wsdl:operation name="newOrder">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:newOrder" name="newOrder">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:newOrderResponse" name="newOrderResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>

<wsdl:binding name="ServerPmtPortalServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:ServerPmtPortalPort">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

    <wsdl:operation name="newOrder">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="newOrder">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="newOrderResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="ServerPmtPortalService">
  <wsdl:port binding="tns:ServerPmtPortalServiceSoapBinding" name="ServerPmtPortalPort">
    <soap:address location="https://stage.service.com/Pmt-proxy/services/v1/paynow"/>
  </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: By the looks of it the wsdl's are different. But best way to check is download a tool like soapui to mock the service. With soapui you can then see the old and new request and response layout and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to make sense of the difference in the WSDL definitions.
From the way the client or stub code is generated, method newOrder for the old WSDL is taking 5 separate parameters: appID, merID, redURL, uname, cmt.
The new WSDL method is taking only one parameter, which is newOrderRequest which in turn contains 5 properties.
I generated the new stub and using it, and told the respective people that we cannot point to the new WSDL without making changes to the code.